# Guess the final term of a converging series

Tags: convergence

I have a non-linear equation that converges, and reaches suitable accuracy after around 20 steps, however each step is very expensive to calculate. The series are never quite the same, but they are similar; there are 4 examples below. Ideally, I would like to be able to guess the final answer (getting as close as possible), knowing only the first few (say 5?) steps.

Example series:

22.1365571473
39.1003909811
60.8702429029
87.3193552323
117.479117043
149.298938154
180.099415362
207.478769226
230.033683334
247.487707416
260.35893824
269.520601585
275.88012284
280.218467629
283.143170475
285.099206545
286.400448741
287.263033108
287.833493354

43.8168649647
119.274730769
228.310938956
332.800659827
406.364683614
449.036198231
471.258177801
482.206944282
487.456776422
489.94148426
491.110264146
491.658457589

13.7709904649
17.4517204683
20.862400148
23.9136500982
26.5768107479
28.8599125041
30.7910913202
32.4079080805
33.7507827028
34.8591665245
35.7694839095
36.5141882847
37.1214961348
37.6155120979
38.016560732
38.3416106934
38.6047214436
38.8174732756
38.9893605432
39.1281383997
39.2401237101
39.3304495994
39.4032795394

19.5526511118
31.7547501442
45.9545707135
61.7006795681
78.515831743
95.8079163675
112.898129782
129.114767641
143.90065881
156.888846484
167.923989061
177.034730079
184.379068592
190.185787294
194.706624478
198.184227677
200.8346208
202.840305035
204.349975449
205.481710536
206.327550943
206.958285211
207.427820219
207.776913165

Comment: As I understand, you have an equation in 4 variables ($x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$) that your are trying to solve. Could you write down this equation (not in Python code but in mathematical script)?

Comment: @GertVdE, I started writing it out in mathematics, and then I realised that what I was doing was just plain wrong. Sorry. I've removed the code snippet from my question.

Comment: OK. Just come back when you're ready...

Comment: 20 steps of what?

Comment: I wouldn't see this as the problem of predicting a limit of a sequence. This is a model identification problem. See @RodyOldenhuis answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shanks Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation) is a good way to improve the convergence of a series. There are some other [series acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) methods described on Wikipedia too.

[Bender and Orzsag's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989315) also has an entire chapter on summation of series (although I don't have it handy now).

Comment: Thanks, I've applied Aitken's delta-squared process (which I found in your link to the Shanks transform) and that gets sufficient accuracy in roughly 3 iterations of 3 steps, which pretty much halves the time. So far it seems to be robust too.

Answer (score 2):

The series you show appear to have roughly the first three significant digits stable by the last term you show.

In most of those same series, the first 5 steps have not gotten you to a correct first significant digit. On a log scale, this is a huge distance. To ask for a prediction that far out from so few terms is, to put it charitably, insanely optimistic.

As well, be incredibly careful with multiple iterations of methods such as Shanks (as one response suggested.) That method tends to massively amplify floating point noise in your computations, so that after several iterations of that method, the noise has grown enough to overwhelm the signal. The point is, IF you do apply Shanks, only a few iterations will be of any value.

Is it impossible to predict a limit from such a sequence after only a few terms? I won't say that, but to do any kind of a decent job, YOU need to provide input. Extrapolation (which is what you are doing) is a NASTY process, fraught with problems. However, if you can supply useful information that restricts the family of curves one might expect to see in this process, then the problem becomes far more tractable. (This is not always easy to do.)

Comment: I totally agree that it's optimistic to do it in 1 jump. I should have worded my question better to make it obvious that I'm happy with an iterative process. The Aitken transformation seems to work best for my problem

Answer (score 1):

Given by how you state the problem, I take it accuracy is not a really important issue here :)

For your data sets: the fist-order differences ($a_2-a_1, a_3-a_2, ...$) look like they could be part of a [Gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

So you could detect whether a peak occurs in the first-order differences, and stop evaluating your generator function when it does. Fit a Gaussian to the data points you have thus far to obtain $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and extrapolate to infinity.

The result should be close to the value of the Gaussian CDF for those values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

It'll be a nice ballpark estimate, so if that suffices for the rest of your application, it should be OK. But please don't expect this to be anywhere near accurate -- fitting a Gaussian accurately through 5 data points is, well...you'll have to be extremely lucky :)

Comment: Cheers, I've tried this and like you implied it sometimes works well and other times doesn't give a particularly good guess. It seems to always gets a good enough approximation in 3 iterations, but it's more expensive than an Aitken transformation because that only needs 2 calculations per iteration, rather than 4.